# Does Spark support Arabic text analysis

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I would like to analyze Arabic tweets, Does Spark support the Arabic Language?

Answer (score 1):

Spark itself doesn't process or analyzes any language. It doesn't have built-in NLP (natural language processing) capabilities like sentiment analysis, you have to use other libraries/frameworks for this.

Spark Streaming just allows you to ingest set of strings in a reliable distributed manner. As long as you use UTF-8 (which is the default for both Spark and Twitter) Twitter messages will be preserved as-is.

Comment: Thank you, Do you have any suggestions for what I can use with Spark to Analyze Arabic tweets?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What task are you supposed to solve?

Comment: Sentiment analysis